# Swift sequences prefix(while:) return not all elements

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence

I have an issue. I am testing usage of the `prefix(while:)` and receive not expected result.Count of elements after `prefix(while:)` is missing one element. From the code it is possible to see that structures with name that has prefix Oleg are 5 but after `prefix(while:)` it returns 4.

Example :

```
struct User {
    let name: String
}

let users = [User(name : "Oleg 1"),User(name : "Oleg 2"),User(name : "Oleg 3"),User(name : "Oleg 4"),User(name : "Igor 1"),User(name : "Oleg 5"),User(name : "Max 1")]


print(users.prefix { $0.name.hasPrefix("Oleg") }.count) //4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the `Array prefix` method:

> Returns a subsequence containing the initial elements until predicate returns false and skipping the remaining elements.

When the code gets to the "Igor 1" instance, `prefix` stops and returns that first subrange giving the result of 4.

Don't confuse the `Array prefix` method and the `String hasPrefix` method. They are used for two completely different things.

Perhaps you want to use `filter`.

```
print(users.filter { $0.name.hasPrefix("Oleg") }.count) // 5
```

Comment: My bad really miss this part. Thanks for help.